# How to install old apache version on Debian 8

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

Main issue is the new Apache breaks a few things on my webserver. I even tried using `HttpProtocolOptions unsafe` in `apache2.conf` but it didn't work as desired.

The only way out for me is use old version - 2.4.10-10+deb8u7.

Now when I do `apt-cache showpkg apache2` it shows me 2.4.10-10+deb8u12.

How do I install 2.4.10-10+deb8u7? I had to re-install Jessie and it seems cache doesn't have the version I had before.

Comment: Maybe the real question would be asking how to work with the newer versions. Sooner or later you will have to deal with that, and then there are the security issues, possibly new functionalities and installation conflicts.

Comment: Even with new version, I tried it. I can't figure out the way so for time being, I would like to use old version and get it going and then figure out long term solution.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - even adding HttpProtocolOptions unsafe doesn't resolve the issue. By any chance you know any work around for that? So that extended ASCII characters can be passed on URL? - Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Running an older version of Apache 2 such as 2.4.10-10+deb8u7 is a rather bad idea, since it contains a number of known vulnerabilities.

However, if you do want to pursue this avenue, you’ll find the package on [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/apache2/2.4.10-10%2Bdeb8u7/). You can download the packages manually from that link, or follow the instructions on the “Usage” section of [the main page](http://snapshot.debian.org/) to add an APT repository containing the packages you’re interested in:

```
deb [ check-valid-until=no ] https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20160919T052119Z/ jessie main
```

(you need `check-valid-until=no` for snapshots because the timestamps aren’t updated; it’s not a good idea to use this in other circumstances).

Comment: I tried to follow what it's mentioned on that link but I am having hard time to find out correct steps. I found the package listed here - https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/apache2/2.4.10-10+deb8u7   how do I find the correct source link? Ex like this one? deb     https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20091004T111800Z/ lenny main
I use Jessie so trying to figure out what correct link I need to do add? I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: I tried to search for apache version on that page and it gives me pretty much super old versions. Ex - http://snapshot.debian.org/package/apache/

Comment: Did you try following the first link in my answer? It will take you straight to a list of `apache2` packages.